# Wordpress: additional meta data for user

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add user data when registering, like middle name and many others.
I have found that I can add it to wp-includes/user.php in function _get_additional_user_keys and add them to $keys, but when user edit his profile, and submit changes, that data is not saved in database, and that meta is empty.

Does anyone know what else should I do?
Thank you

edit:

in \wp-admin\user-edit.php, i have added:

```
<tr>
    <th><label for="last_name2"><?php _e('Middle name') ?></label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name2" id="last_name2" value="<?php echo esc_attr($profileuser->last_name2) ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
</tr>
```

and now in my db I got meta_key without value in table wp_usermeta

Dorijan

Comment: Where did you look in the database for the middle name?

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141502/wordpress-create-a-new-usermeta-field-for-users