# WordPress - how to check user meta at login

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a custom wordpress plugin to manage user registrations. I have created two custom roles, that are named `customer` and `merchant`, the merchant role users are created from the admin of the site. I need to assig to each merchant account a custom meta to identify it, but from the wp user admin panel this is not possible.

In the registration form for customers I have a field that will be saved inside the user meta table and will contain a code that will be selected from the user from a dropdown menù and is used to identify the merchants.

```php
<?php

wp_insert_user( 
  array(
   'meta_input' => array('merchant_code' => '001'), // this code is passed from the frontend
   'role' => 'customer'
  ) 
);

?>
```

I'm not sure if is possible with a flter or an hook, but what I need is to check for this code when the merchant users will login, this because I will show to each merchant a different customers list. Any suggestion about?

Comment: What do you mean by: `"the merchant role users are created from the admin of the site."` and `"...but from the wp user admin panel this is not possible."`.

Comment: @amarinediary I mean that the admin will create the merchant account from the user creation page `wp-admin/user-new.php`.  In this page there isn't the ability to add custom meta for the account that will be created.

Comment: @newbiedev you can definitely add custom meta in the new user / user edit screens in the admin panel.

Comment: @CornelRaiu what is the correct way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress: Create a new usermeta field for users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141502/wordpress-create-a-new-usermeta-field-for-users)

Comment: You may use this hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_new_form/ .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`user_register`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) action hook to intercept the user registration.

We then generate a pseudo random identifier based on the user registration timestamp and the user id.

We retrieve the userdata through [`get_userdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/) and update them through [`wp_update_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/) (which fetch his arguments from [`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/)).

The following is untested but should work:

```php
<?php

add_action( 'user_register', function ( $user_id ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $pseudo_random_identifier = null;
    $pseudo_random_identifier .= $user_id;
    $pseudo_random_identifier .= str_replace( array( '-', ' ', ':', ), '', $user->user_registered );
    $pseudo_random_identifier .= sanitize_title_with_dashes( $pseudo_random_identifier );
    $userdata = array (
        'ID' => $user_id, 
        'meta_input' => array(
            'merchant_code' => $pseudo_random_identifier,
        ),
    );
    
    wp_update_user( $userdata );
} );
```

Tho for your information, you can change the user role too.

Comment: the merchant code is already available, so I don't need to generate it but only to add it from the `user-new.php` page. The ideal is to add an input field to that page?

Comment: Alright. No need, you should be able to access it somehow, if you're using a plugin then you should take a look at the devs documentation.

Comment: I'm writing my own plugin. Anyway I will do a search to find a way to edit the `user-new.php` page